# What's wrong with my 12 days of christmas Assembly program?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

This assembly program won't compile, the only output I get is:

```
✗ ./12d                            
On day 1 of Christmas my true love sent to me
[1]    35274 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./12d
```

when I compiled the code with `gcc -no-pie 12daysofxmas.s -o 12d`.

Here is the Assembly code of the file 12daysofxmas.s:

```
.globl main

.section .rodata
intro: .string "On day %ld of Christmas my true love sent to me\n"
and_s: .string "and "

str01: .string "%ld partridge in a pear tree\n"
str02: .string "%ld turtle doves\n"
str03: .string "%ld french hens\n"
str04: .string "%ld calling birds\n"
str05: .string "%ld gold rings\n"
str06: .string "%ld geese a-laying\n"
str07: .string "%ld swans a-swimming\n"
str08: .string "%ld maids a-milking\n"
str09: .string "%ld ladies dancing\n"
str10: .string "%ld lords a-leaping\n"
str11: .string "%ld pipers piping\n"
str12: .string "%ld drummers drumming\n"

lines:
    .quad str01, str02, str03, str04, str05, str06
    .quad str07, str08, str09, str10, str11, str12



.section .text
main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    movq $1, %rcx                 # counter for days (1 to 12)
    movq lines(%rip), %rdx        # address of the lines array

.loop_day:
    movq $intro, %rdi            # load address of the intro string
    movq %rcx, %rsi              # load the current day
    call printf                   # print intro

    movq $1, %r8                  # counter for gifts (1 to day)
.loop_gift:
    cmpq %r8, %rcx                # compare gifts with days
    jg .next_day                  # jump to next day if gifts > days

    cmpq $1, %r8                  # check if it's the first day
    jne .print_gift               # if not, print the gift

    # if it's the first day, don't print "and"
    cmpq $1, %rcx
    je .print_gift

    # print "and " before the last line in every verse except the first
    movq $and_s, %rdi
    call printf

.print_gift:
    leaq -1(%r8), %r9             # calculate (r8 - 1) into r9 for correct indexing
    movq (%rdx, %r9, 8), %rdi     # load address of the current gift string
    movq %r8, %rsi                # load the current gift count
    call printf                   # print the gift string

    incq %r8                      # increment the gift counter
    jmp .loop_gift                # loop through gifts

.next_day:
    movq $10, %rdi                # ASCII code for newline character
    call putchar                  # print a newline character
    incq %rcx                     # increment the day counter
    cmpq $12, %rcx                # check if all days are done
    jle .loop_day                 # if not, loop through days

    leave
    ret
```

Here is a good description of the task at hand:

> Implement a GNU Assembly program that prints a alightly modified
> version of the "Twelve Days of Christmas" song.
> Instead of "first day, second day" or "1st day, 2nd day" etc, your program may output "On day N of Christmas my true love gave to
> me".
> This song is cumulative - each day will include the gifts of every previous day.
> (i.e. day 1 will include only a partridge, while day 2 will include two turtle doves AND a partridge).
> Use printf to output the lyrics of the song to terminal.
> A suggestion for the first lines of the output is added below.
>
> **HINTS**:
>
> - The registers %rdi and %rsi are used for the first two arguments in a function call (like printf).
> - Some registers are overwritten by functions (including printf!) This includes %rax, %rbx, %rcx, %rdx, %rdi, %rsi, %rbp, %rsp, and %r8-r15.
>   - The order of comparisons are (for some reason) reversed! This means that cmp %r8, %r9 will compare r9 vs r8.
> - Create a debug helper string that you can call with printf for slightly easier debugging.
> - Consult the examples in (../examples/) for inspiration. Make them with `make`.
> - Use a cheat sheet like https://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs421/papers/x86-asm/asm.html or https://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs033/docs/guides/x64_cheatsheet.pdf
>   - Compile this with `make` once finished.
>
> **BONUS POINTS** (Can only be exchanged for bragging rights)
>
> - Use putchar to easily create new lines so that the finished song doesn't become a giant wall of text.
> - Make the song include "and" before the last line - i.e., "AND 1 partridge in a pear tree" - in every verse except the first.
>
> **SUGGESTED OUTPUT**:
>
> ```
>    On day 1 of Christmas my true love sent to me
>    1 partridge in a pear tree
>
>    On day 2 of Christmas my true love sent to me
>    2 turtle doves
>    and 1 partridge in a pear tree
>
>    On day 3 of Christmas my true love sent to me
>    3 french hens
>    2 turtle doves
>    and 1 partridge in a pear tree
>
>    ...
> ```

Comment: For starters you ignored one of the hints, namely: _"Some registers are overwritten by functions (including printf!) This includes %rax, %rbx, %rcx"_ ... so your `rcx` counter is already overwritten by the first `printf`.

Comment: You have been told that not all the registers are preserved across a call. Use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`) to what this means (hint: check the value of `rdx`). Furthermore, this instruction `movq $intro, %rdi` won't work in PIE.

Comment: Ah, the gift of a segfault!

Comment: All kidding aside, when something segfaults, it happens on exactly one instruction.  One way to debug a segfault, is to look at what the program is doing when that instruction occurs.  A segfault ia a memory access error, meaning the program is try to access memory it shouldn't be using, so find out how that instruction got or formed a bad address.  Usually, we look backwards to prior instructions to find why some address value went wrong.  Also, get to know your data so you know what good addresses look like, many environments, debuggers, IDE's have tools to help with that.

Comment: It obviously does compile, otherwise you wouldn't have an executable to run.  But actually "assemble", not "compile".